# How to get the programming language icons used the external evaluation cells?

Tags: front-end, external-language-cell

How to get the language icons used in the external language evaluation cells?

Here is a screenshot of the cells:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After examining the output:

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "ExternalLanguage"}]
```

we can come up with the following command:

```
aProgIcons = 
 Association[# -> RawBoxes@#2 & @@@ ExternalEvaluate`FE`GetExternalLanguageMenuData[]]
```

[image]

**Remark:** The values of the association are Graphics(Box), so they can be rasterized or exported in whatever format.

```
FullForm[aProgIcons[[1]]]

(* RawBoxes[GraphicsBox[
  List[Thickness[0.05`], 
   List[FaceForm[List[RGBColor[1.`, 1.`, 1.`], Opacity[1.`]]], 
    FilledCurveBox[List[List[List[1, 4, 3], List[1, 3, 3], ... *)
```

---

*Thanks to Kuba for providing this answer!*